# Клиенсткая часть, расчет контрольной суммы файла и передача на сервер

Tags: header, html, frontend, javascript

Просто ради интереса.
Есть ли возможность? обычными средствами? перед закачкой какого-то файла отправить  заголовок с контрольной суммой, или что-то в этом роде, чтобы не закачивать снова один и тот же файл, а чтобы проверилось сразу и вернуло файл просто.

Я думаю, вы поняли:) Спасибо.

Comment: HTML5 / FileAPI, не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похожий вопрос на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/768287/238336).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, только если сервер поддерживает это, и описал как этой возможностью пользоваться.